# Can't Click on UITabelCell after implementing UIRefreshControl

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I have recently implemented the RefreshControl on my ViewController which contains UITableDataSource and Delegate. When you click on each cell of the table, it leads to other view controller but after implementing the refresh control, I can no longer click on each cell. Is it because I added the subview(refreshControl) to the view?

Here is the code below,

```
 tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refresh:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)


func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
    // Code to refresh table view
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

}
```

Comment: tableViewController.refreshControl  = self.refreshControl ?

Comment: What's up with that?